# How does 0 get assigned to the variable 'a'?

Tags: c, pointers

I wrote a simple program in C (newbie in C)

when i try to compile this program it's get compiled.

created pointer to int 'p' and store the address of of variable 'a'

when i derefernce the pointer it show the value 0 but i never assigned any value

to my variable so where does 0 come from ?
and if  we write 
    `int a;` 
it allocates space in the memory even before assigning any value to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    int *p = &a;
    printf("%d\n", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

compiler : clang

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of an uninitialized variable is *indeterminate*. Reading from an uninitialized variable is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So anything can happen. `0` is also a possible result of that.

[C11 standard says:](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p10)

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

and

[indeterminate value](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.19.2p1) is defined as:

> either an unspecified value or a trap representation

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't come from anywhere! It's an arbitrary value.

You didn't initialise `a`, so what happens when you try to print its value is completely unpredictable.